# Displaying stylesheets / js from single source under multiple domains

Tags: php, cpanel, multiple-domains

I have about 20 or so domains that are used as landing pages. These 20 domains all for the most part have the same styling, images, and js files. Instead of having to manually update stylesheets or js files for each and every domain anytime I make a change, I want them all to be from one single source. My problem is that these domains are setup as add-on domains on cpanel. If I use ../, it does not work, it just uses the domain the page is under instead of the parent domain.

1. What is the best way of setting up a single source for all files and at the same time have code as clean as possible?

Comment: Put the common files in a single domain. Then use `//maindomain.com/js/whatever.js` and `//maindomain.com/css/something.css`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why just linking them all from a single domain didn't work. I had cloudflare enabled and I was seeing cached pages. After turning development mode on, the changes worked.